# Pass variable to awk pattern

Tags: regex, shell, awk, glob

I am writing a shell script which calls an awk script and then I take some user input in the BEGIN using getline, and I save the input to some variables.

```
BEGIN {printf "What's the word?"
getline word < "-"
}
```

Now, one of these variables is called "word" and I want to use it in another pattern in the script to print all lines containing the word given. I tried something like this:

```
/(^| )word( |$)/
```

which will print all lines containing the word "word", and I know that it's not gonna work because it's not recognized as being a variable. I'd searched a lot and found patterns starting with

```
$0~
```

but it's not working either in my case. Is there a way I could pass a variable to this pattern and print all lines containing the word stored in the variable?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the pattern in [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script)?

Comment: I know that the -v option can be used for variables, but that would pass it from the shell to the awk script, and I tried to read the input in the BEGIN section instead of the shell itself.

Comment: Frankly, doing the read from the shell rather than from awk strikes me as in most circumstances the sensible approach -- that way your awk script's input can be from a non-terminal source if need be. But... *shrug*, you know your runtime context better than I do, and orthogonal to the question asked here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a BEGIN section to build a variable with your full pattern, you can refer to it later:

```
awk -v word="hello" '
  BEGIN {
    pattern = "(^|[[:space:]])" word "([[:space:]]|$)"
  }

  $0 ~ pattern { print $0 }
'
```

...that said, you don't even need to do that, if you don't mind the overhead of reconstructing the pattern for every line:

```
awk -v word="hello" '$0 ~ ("(^|[[:space:]])" word "([[:space:]]|$)") { print $0 }'
```

(Why `[[:space:]]` instead of ? That way tabs and other whitespace characters other than hex-20 vanilla spaces can also act as word separators).

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 0):

another alternative is using the word boundary, which you can apply in the variable with some backslash escaping

```
 awk -v v="\\\y$word\\\y" '$0~v' file
```

not sure all `awk`s support this though.  Alternatively you can use `\<` and `\>` for the left and right boundaries.